# counting returned values of unique( )

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe,df1

```
     Date        inp  name   
0  2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC 
1  2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC      
2  2017-08-08  2.3.6  TAC         
3  2017-08-22  2.5.9  TTT         
4  2017-09-23  0.8.0  TAC         
5  2017-10-09  2.3.6  ABC         
6  2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC
7  2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC                  
8  2017-10-23  0.8.0  TAC         
9  2017-11-08  6.2.6  ABC
```

then another dataframe,df2

```
                2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC  2.5.9TTT      
August            2         1            0            
September         0         0            0             
October           1         2            0             
November          0         0            1
```

another dataframe,df3

```
                2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC       
August            2         1                      
September         0         0                         
October           1         2                        
November          0         0
```

I want to get the distinct values in column: 'inp' of df1 which in this case is 4. Then, number of columns of df2 and df3 which is 3 and 2 in this case. How can I store the number of columns of the 2 dataframes,df2 and df3  in a new dataframe by renaming the index, then getting the percentage df2 and df3 in df1. It should look like this:

```
                     noOfColumn      pct
    df2 as sat         3         3/4=75                      
    df3 as nath        2         2/4=50
```

I have not been able to go past this point

```
st=pd.Dataframe(df1)
st=df['inp'].unique()
st2=st.count()
```

because I keep getting this: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: count() is not a valid method. Try `len(st)` or `st.size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a list of your dataframes -

```
df_list = [df2, df3]
```

Inside a loop, build a list of series (there are other ways to do this, but here's one) with the column count and index having the name -

```
r = [
     pd.Series(len(df.columns), index=['df{}'.format(i)]) 
     for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 2)
]
```

Or,

```
r = []
for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 2):
    r.append(pd.Series(len(df.columns), index=['df{}'.format(i)]))
```

Now, concatenate, and compute the `pct` change. Also, you want `nunique`, to get the number of unique values (`unique` + `size` as the other answer recommends is not pandaic) -

```
v = pd.concat(r).to_frame(name='noOfColumn')  
v['pct'] = v['noOfColumn'] / df1.inp.nunique()

v

     noOfColumn   pct
df2           3  0.75
df3           2  0.50
```

---

An alternative way of doing this would be collecting your index and values in separate lists, and calling the `DataFrame` constructor once -

```
idx, v = [], []
for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 2):
    idx.append('df{}'.format(i))
    v.append(len(df.columns))
```

Finally,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(v, index=idx, columns=['noOfColumn'])
df['pct'] = df['noOfColumn'] / df1.inp.nunique()

df    
     noOfColumn   pct
df2           3  0.75
df3           2  0.50
```

Comment: @Bode You're welcome. Good luck with the rest of your work.

Comment: It will really be cool if the names of the 2 dataframes could be named asides df2,df3. when I change it to other names, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Bode You just need to modify this line: `idx.append('df{}'.format(i))` with whatever name you like.

Comment: Sorry I meant 4 dataframes with names like: dty,fre, gst and dev. so I put all these names in df_list[dty,dtt, dst,dve] but the index remains the default python index and not  the name of the dataframes

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want is size, not count, according to the docs at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

size gives the number of items in the ndarray.

Comment: Nah, this doesn't answer the question.